# How to get a geometry from a COLLADA (.dae) file with SceneKit

Tags: geometry, scenekit, collada

I need to read the `<geometry>` in a COLLADA file in order to create the array of morph targets and animate the mesh from the base geometry to the target geometries.

I can only access the geometry from the base geometry that's embedded in the Node (the COLLADA file only have one `<node>`):

```
planeNode.geometry = scene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Plane", recursively: true)!.geometry
```

Here's the full source code of the COLLADA file (have 3 geometries and 1 node but only get access to 1 geometry):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
  <asset>
    <contributor>
      <author>Blender User</author>
      <authoring_tool>Blender 2.77.0 commit date:2016-04-05, commit time:18:12, hash:abf6f08</authoring_tool>
    </contributor>
    <unit name="meter" meter="1"/>
    <up_axis>Z_UP</up_axis>
  </asset>
  <library_images/>
  <library_geometries>
    <geometry id="Plane-mesh" name="Plane">
      <mesh>
        <source id="Plane-mesh-positions">
          <float_array id="Plane-mesh-positions-array" count="12">-1 -1 0 1 -1 0 -1 1 0 1 1 0</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Plane-mesh-positions-array" count="4" stride="3">
              <param name="X" type="float"/>
              <param name="Y" type="float"/>
              <param name="Z" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <source id="Plane-mesh-normals">
          <float_array id="Plane-mesh-normals-array" count="3">0 0 1</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Plane-mesh-normals-array" count="1" stride="3">
              <param name="X" type="float"/>
              <param name="Y" type="float"/>
              <param name="Z" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <vertices id="Plane-mesh-vertices">
          <input semantic="POSITION" source="#Plane-mesh-positions"/>
        </vertices>
        <polylist count="2">
          <input semantic="VERTEX" source="#Plane-mesh-vertices" offset="0"/>
          <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#Plane-mesh-normals" offset="1"/>
          <vcount>3 3 </vcount>
          <p>1 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 3 0 2 0</p>
        </polylist>
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
    <geometry id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key1" name="Key1">
      <mesh>
        <source id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key1-positions">
          <float_array id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key1-positions-array" count="12">-1 -1 0 1 -1 0 -1 1 0 1 2 0</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Plane-mesh_morph_Key1-positions-array" count="4" stride="3">
              <param name="X" type="float"/>
              <param name="Y" type="float"/>
              <param name="Z" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <source id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key1-normals">
          <float_array id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key1-normals-array" count="6">0 0 1 0 0 1</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Plane-mesh_morph_Key1-normals-array" count="2" stride="3">
              <param name="X" type="float"/>
              <param name="Y" type="float"/>
              <param name="Z" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <vertices id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key1-vertices">
          <input semantic="POSITION" source="#Plane-mesh_morph_Key1-positions"/>
        </vertices>
        <polylist count="2">
          <input semantic="VERTEX" source="#Plane-mesh_morph_Key1-vertices" offset="0"/>
          <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#Plane-mesh_morph_Key1-normals" offset="1"/>
          <vcount>3 3 </vcount>
          <p>1 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 3 1 2 1</p>
        </polylist>
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
    <geometry id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key2" name="Key2">
      <mesh>
        <source id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key2-positions">
          <float_array id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key2-positions-array" count="12">-1 -1 0 1 -1 0 -1 1 0 2 1 0</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Plane-mesh_morph_Key2-positions-array" count="4" stride="3">
              <param name="X" type="float"/>
              <param name="Y" type="float"/>
              <param name="Z" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <source id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key2-normals">
          <float_array id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key2-normals-array" count="3">0 0 1</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Plane-mesh_morph_Key2-normals-array" count="1" stride="3">
              <param name="X" type="float"/>
              <param name="Y" type="float"/>
              <param name="Z" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <vertices id="Plane-mesh_morph_Key2-vertices">
          <input semantic="POSITION" source="#Plane-mesh_morph_Key2-positions"/>
        </vertices>
        <polylist count="2">
          <input semantic="VERTEX" source="#Plane-mesh_morph_Key2-vertices" offset="0"/>
          <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#Plane-mesh_morph_Key2-normals" offset="1"/>
          <vcount>3 3 </vcount>
          <p>1 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 3 0 2 0</p>
        </polylist>
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
  </library_geometries>
  <library_controllers>
    <controller id="Plane-morph" name="Plane-morph">
      <morph source="#Plane-mesh" method="NORMALIZED">
        <source id="Plane-targets">
          <IDREF_array id="Plane-targets-array" count="2">Plane-mesh_morph_Key1 Plane-mesh_morph_Key2</IDREF_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Plane-targets-array" count="2" stride="1">
              <param name="IDREF" type="IDREF"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <source id="Plane-weights">
          <float_array id="Plane-weights-array" count="2">0 0</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor source="#Plane-weights-array" count="2" stride="1">
              <param name="MORPH_WEIGHT" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <targets>
          <input semantic="MORPH_TARGET" source="#Plane-targets"/>
          <input semantic="MORPH_WEIGHT" source="#Plane-weights"/>
        </targets>
      </morph>
    </controller>
  </library_controllers>
  <library_visual_scenes>
    <visual_scene id="Scene" name="Scene">
      <node id="Plane" name="Plane" type="NODE">
        <matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 0 0 -4.37114e-8 -1 0 0 1 -4.37114e-8 0 0 0 0 1</matrix>
        <instance_geometry url="#Plane-mesh" name="Plane"/>
      </node>
    </visual_scene>
  </library_visual_scenes>
  <scene>
    <instance_visual_scene url="#Scene"/>
  </scene>
</COLLADA>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately SceneKit doesn't read the geometries tag, so we have to create nodes with the geometries associated and then hide those. Not the best but for a lack of better way it worked. Working code here: [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/178847#178847)

Answer (score -1):

you can use [entryWithIdentifier:withClass:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenesource/1573762-entrywithidentifier) to retrieve objects that are not in the scene graph. Alternatively, in your authoring tool, you can attach the morpher to a node and then use the `morpher` property of a node to retrieve its target geometries.

Comment: Thanks @mnuages. Can you help me understand the second option with code?

Comment: I've tried the first option and still only get access to one geometry

`func loadGeometriesFromSceneSource(sceneSource: SCNSceneSource) {
        
        let identifiers = sceneSource.identifiersOfEntriesWithClass(SCNGeometry.self) as [String]
        
        for identifier in identifiers {
            print(identifier) // it only gets me the Base Geometry
            morphs.append(sceneSource.entryWithIdentifier(identifier, withClass: SCNGeometry.self)!)
        }
    }`


What am I doing wrong?...